# Facebook Graph API : Publishing likes through the API is no longer available

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook Graph API

While try to post likes, I am getting below error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Publishing likes through the API is no longer available",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3,
    "fbtrace_id": "C9I3NJ2I9Gt"
  }
}
```

http://prnt.sc/d973z5

So anyhow, I can post a likes to object/post?

Is there any other way to do same thing?

Comment: The documentation and changelog don't say anything about this being removed. Suggest you file a bug report, and ask them what's up, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ (If you do, please share the link to the bug report here; I asked about this in the FB Developers Group, too, and would share the bug report link with others that are interested in this.)

Comment: OK, I just found https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1754734484744033/, that seems to be related.

Comment: @CBroe, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1364122110273306/

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, Facebook has removed the feature. Here is the response from facebook team. :(

> Shireesh Asthana:Facebook Team
>
> Hi everyone,
>
> Thanks again for reporting this and for your patience. We made the
>   difficult decision to restrict access to this functionality of the
>   Graph API to better maintain the quality standards of our community.
>
> We're sorry that we had to take this step. Thank you for helping us
>   keep the Facebook platform a safe place for our community and
>   developers.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Shireesh

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1754734484744033/

Comment: Thank you for linking to this bug report, this looks like the only place they have confirmed it. Documentation has not been updated as yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes facebook removed this feature permanently you can only do with page access tokens and only pages can like the post of any other pages.

You can read our updated docs & changelog here:
Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/likes
Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog